# how to extract the PID of a process by command line

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get the PID of a process namely "cron" by command line.
I tried the following script.

```
ps ax|grep 'cron'
```

but I am getting a part of a table,

```
   1427 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
24160 pts/5    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

How I extract the pid from this ?

Comment: Use : `pgrep cron`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`pidof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pidof), rather to use other commands and apply post-processing actions on them.

```
$ pidof cron
22434
```

To make the command return only one `PID` pertaining to to the process, use the `-s` flag

> -s
>   Single shot - this instructs the program to only return one pid.

Answer (score 4):

The `pgrep` utility will return the process IDs for the currently running processes matching its argument:

```
$ pgrep cron
228
```

It may also be used to "grep for" things on the command line:

```
$ pgrep -f uerfale
69749
69752

$ pgrep -l -f uerfale
69749 slogin uerfale
69752 slogin: /home/kk/.ssh/sockets/uerfale-9022-kk.sock [mux] m
```

To *kill* a process by name, use `pkill`.  It works in the same way as `pgrep` but will send a signal to the matched processes instead of outputting a process ID.

Answer (score 2):

Like this, for example:

```
ps -ef|grep 'cron'|grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: here's a shortcut to exclude the grep process: `ps -ef | awk '/[c]ron/ {print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this;

```
ps -o pid,sess,cmd afx | egrep "( |/)cron( -f)?$"
```

or

```
pstree -pas <cronPID>
```